# Supervisors' details in cover page

Tags: titles, thesis, report, covers

I would like to add the details of two supervisors to my title page. It is supposed to look like this:

[image]

Could anyone please guide on what changes to be made to the Cover page code? Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/47927)! Please show us some code of yours: How do you generate your title page? Depending on the document class and the packages you use, there are different ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: \begin{titlepage}
  \centering

  \IfFileExists{logos/abc.pdf}{%
    \includegraphics[height=20mm]{logos/abc.pdf}
  }{%
    \vspace*{20mm}
  }
  \vspace{5mm}
  {\huge\MakeUppercase{\getFaculty{}}}\\
  \vspace{5mm}
  {\large\MakeUppercase{\getUniversity{}}}\\
  \vspace{20mm}
  {\Large \getDoctype{}}
  \vspace{15mm}
  {\huge\bfseries \getTitle{}}

  \vspace{15mm}
  \begin{tabular}{l l}
    Author:          & \getAuthor{} \\
    Supervisor:      & \getSupervisor{} \\
    Submission Date: & \getSubmissionDate{} \\
  \end{tabular}

\end{titlepage}

Comment: The above was how it is in the template. And details were defined like:                                                                              \newcommand*{\getSupervisor}{abcdef}                                                                                   But this allowed only one supervisor and just the name (one line).

Comment: You should add this to your question by editing it.

Comment: @JasperHabicht  Oh, that's how it works! Thank you! Thank you for your responses.

Comment: It is always better to share your code, because then other are more likely to be able to help you. Also, code in the comments is a bit hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is MWE based on the code you commented. It uses a `pbox` (a parbox that calculates its necessary minimum width) to allow for line breaks in a table cell.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{pbox}

\newcommand{\getAuthor}{Author}
\newcommand{\getDoctype}{Doctype}
\newcommand{\getTitle}{Title}
\newcommand{\getUniversity}{University}
\newcommand{\getFaculty}{Faculty}
\newcommand{\getSupervisor}{\textbf{Supervisor 1}\\
Designation of Supervisor 1\\ 
Chair of ABC \\[2em] 
\textbf{Supervisor 2}\\ 
Designation of supervisor 2\\
Chair of ABC}
\newcommand{\getSubmissionDate}{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage} 
    \centering 
    \IfFileExists{logos/abc.pdf}{% 
    \includegraphics[height=20mm]{logos/abc.pdf} }{% 
    \vspace*{20mm} } 
    \vspace{5mm}
    {\huge\MakeUppercase{\getFaculty{}}}\\ 
    \vspace{5mm}
    {\large\MakeUppercase{\getUniversity{}}}\\ 
    \vspace{20mm}
    {\Large \getDoctype{}}\\
    \vspace{15mm}
    {\huge\bfseries \getTitle{}}\\
    \vspace{15mm} 
    \begin{tabular}{l l} 
        Author: & \getAuthor{} \\ 
        Supervisor: & \pbox[t]{5cm}{\getSupervisor{}} \\ 
        Submission Date: & \getSubmissionDate{} \\
    \end{tabular} 
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Result of code above]

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. Just with the addition of \usepackage{pbox}